# Avoiding for loop in matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

For a matrix, A, of shape (m,n) and a diagonal matrix, lambda_diag, of shape (n,n).

```
import numpy as np
m, n = (44, 10)
A = np.random.random((m,n))
lambd = np.random.random(size=n)
lambda_diag = np.diag(lambd)
```

I would like to calculate A @ lambda_diag @ At (where @ is the numpy matrix multiplication operator, and At is the transposed matrix).

I would like to do this for values from (1:n). This is what I would do normally:

```
A_new = np.empty_like(A)
A_new[:, 0] =  (A[:, 0] ** 2) * lambd[0]
for i in range(1, A.shape[1]):
    A_new[:, i] = np.diag(
        A[:, : i + 1]
        @ np.diag(lambd[: i + 1])
        @ A[:, : i + 1].T
    ).flatten()
```

However the use of for loop is slow, and in general it seem cumbersome.
Does numpy have an inbuilt solution for this? Like how you would use `np.einsum()`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. It was supposed to be the matrix A. I have corrected it in the question

Comment: Does the loop give you the desired result? If I naively run `A_new = A@lambda_diag@A.T` it gives me the same thing as `A_new = np.matmul(A,np.matmul( lambda_diag, A.T))`, but not the same as your loop.

Comment: So you are doing the calculation for different size slices of the arrays (on the last dimension).  For a (m,1), (m,2), (m,3) etc sized `A`?  I can't imagine avoiding loops.  Unless you create a 3d `AA`, where the first dimension has these successively larger slices of `A`.  `matmul` can do 'batched' multiplications - that's well documented.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes exactly. Batched multiplication would be a nice solution, but i can't seem to find any documentation under numpys matmul?

Comment: After your edit, I'd like to re-pitch the solution `(A**2 * lambd).cumsum(1)`. Checked with `np.testing.assert_allclose(A_new, (A**2 * lambd).cumsum(1))`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny For this example i like this solution a lot!